# To draw a straight line tangent to two given ellipses.

Tags: euclidean-geometry, conic-sections, geometric-construction, tangent-line

How can I draw a a straight line that touches two ellipses? There are, like for two circles, 4 different solutions. I am not interested in the analytical solution, but in the geometrical drawing, although no matter if conics appear. Thanks.

Comment: Then "algebraic-geometry" is really not a good tag to choose ...

Comment: So, do you mean you want a ruler-and-compass sort of construction? If so, I doubt that this is possible.

Comment: @amWhy -- that's what it says in the question title.

Comment: Argh! You're right @bubba. Silly me!

Comment: Can it be done via ruler-and-compass if the two ellipses are circles of unequal radius?

Comment: I think I have solutions to two given circles, but not two given ellipses

Comment: Yes, I  should have tagged simple "geometry". I'm searching for a synthetic solution, not analytical.

Comment: I guess there are 4 possible tangent lines so just pick one, not sure how to construct an elipse with a compass and ruler only  though

Comment: This is answered at https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3205988/1257, albeit only with a reference to literature that contains the details.

Answer (score 0):

If it is possible to build conics, the solution could be easily found using polar reciprocation. Let $\Gamma_1$, $\Gamma_2$ be given ellipses, and $\Gamma_3$ be the polar reciprocal of second ellipse with respect to first. Tangent to $\Gamma_1$ in its intersection with $\Gamma_3$ is an answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can load the file here into GeoGebra and look in the Construction Protocol to see how the tangents are calculated (in terms of the coefficients of the equation of the conics)
https://help.geogebra.org/topic/tangent-to-ellipse

In short:

- matrix calculation
- construct a hyperbola
- Intersect the hyperbola with one ellipse
- The tangents are then the polar lines of the intersection points

Dynamic Example (drag the points)
https://www.geogebra.org/m/Yr9Jfinu

Credit: https://www.geogebra.org/u/mathmagic

Comment: Where does that hyperbola come from? How can I trace it?